# Scrapy spider only returning last item in list

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm building a scraper to crawl a page and return multiple items (h3 & p tags) from within a div. For some reason, the scraper will print all 'name' fields when called, but is only saving info for the last item on the page.

Here's my code:

```
import scrapy


class FoodSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'food'
    allowed_domains = ['https://blog.feedspot.com/food_blogs/']
    start_urls = ['https://blog.feedspot.com/food_blogs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blogs = response.xpath("//div[@class='fsb v4']")
        for blog in blogs:
            names = blog.xpath('.//h3/a[@class="tlink"]/text()'[0:]).extract()
            links = blog.xpath('.//p/a[@class="ext"]/@href'[0:]).extract()
            locations = blog.xpath('.//p/span[@class="location"]/text()'[0:]).extract()
            abouts = blog.xpath('.//p[@class="trow trow-wrap"]/text()[4]'[0:]).extract()
            post_freqs = blog.xpath('.//p[@class="trow trow-wrap"]/text()[6]'[0:]).extract()
            networks = blog.xpath('.//p[@class="trow trow-wrap"]/text()[9]'[0:]).extract()

            for name in names:
                name.split(',')
                # print(name)
            for link in links:
                link.split(',')
            for location in locations:
                location.split(',')
            for about in abouts:
                about.split(',')
            for post_freq in post_freqs:
                post_freq.split(',')
            for network in networks:
                network.split(',')

            yield {'name': name,
                   'link': link,
                   'location': location,
                   'about': about,
                   'post_freq': post_freq,
                   'network': network
                    }
```

Anyone have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `//div[@class='fsb v4']` in DevTools it will only return a single element

So you have to find a Selector that gets all those profile DIVs

```
class FoodSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'food'
    allowed_domains = ['https://blog.feedspot.com/food_blogs/']
    start_urls = ['https://blog.feedspot.com/food_blogs/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for blog in response.css("p.trow.trow-wrap"):

            yield {'name': blog.css(".thumb.alignnone::attr(alt)").extract_first(),
                   'link': "https://www.feedspot.com/?followfeedid=%s" % blog.css("::attr(data)").extract_first(),
                   'location': blog.css(".location::text").extract_first(),
                    }
```